# Adding a conditional join in entity framework 4.0

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to do an inner join in EF4, but only if a certain condition is met.
I have a function like:

```
List<Articles> Search(int? postSiteId) {
    var myquery =
      from
          articles
      in
          context.Articles
      where
          articles.IsDeleted = 0;

      if(postSiteId != null) {
          // Add an inner join on the Posts table and check that Posts.SiteId = postSiteId ---
      }
}
```

I am unsure how to add the join and the condition inside of the if statement, outside of the main query.  Ive found nothing searching for a few hours.

Im not sure if the join is neccessary though.  If I add a where condition:  `query = query.Where(article => article.Posts.Any(p => p.SiteId == postSiteId.Value))`, will it know to do a join there? Or will it do a subselect?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is *try* it and look at the generated SQL... I suspect it will use a nested subselect, which the query optimizer will work out as a join-like construct, I'd expect.

You *can* do a join yourself, just making sure you select the original value again... but if you're really just interested in finding out wehether any of the posts have the given site ID, your "Any" option is probably cleaner. A normal join would end up returning duplicate articles if there are multiple matching posts. You could use `Distinct`, but it seems a little pointless.

Comment: I did try it, and it generated an inner select.  But, I dont know if that is because of other conditions on the query, or whether I have to explicitly add the join.  Either way, im more interested in what the syntax would be if I decide that I want to add the join anyway if for nothing else but s**ts and giggles.

Comment: @computrius: I'm not sure what you mean. If it's generating SQL which does what you want, isn't that okay for you? You shouldn't need to explicitly add the join if your LINQ query describes what you mean.

Comment: Yes, but if a join is more efficient than an inner select (which is my understanding), I would rather have it do that.  Im kind of new to EF, so im still trying to figure out what I should and shouldnt do.  Lots of things work, but that doesnt mean its the right way to go.

Comment: @computrius: If you want to look for efficiency, you need to look at what the optimizer does - I'm sure it'll use the relevant indexes. Try putting both kinds of query into the profiler, and I suspect you'll find they do basically the same thing.